# Update value of Mysql table inside if else Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I run $search query which returns no. of rows and using if Else  statement

```
If (no. of rows>0{
Update The row where symbol=123;
}else{
Insert new row
}
```

I am able to run the query successfully. I have a column with value (id(primary), name and symbol). I would like to update row value if symbol=123; and insert if it is different then 123.

I am able to insert new row when I enter different symbol but unable to update value although executes successfully if symbol no is same.

Here is my code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM entrance WHERE symbol='15369-2017-02'";
$STH = $db->prepare($sql);
$STH->execute(array(symbol));
$User = $STH->fetch();

if (!empty($User)){

$sql = "UPDATE entrance SET name ='Sagar Rawal'
WHERE symbol='15369-2017-02'";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($sql);
}
else{
   $sql = "INSERT INTO entrance(name,symbol) VALUES (:a,:b)";
   $q = $db->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':b'=>$b));
```

}

But when I run from Mysql command panel below code

```
UPDATE entrance SET name="Ritish Karki" WHERE symbol="15369-2017-02"
```

Then value change successfully. 
Any help?

Comment: `where symbol=15369-2017-02` is comparing `symbol` with `15369-2017-02 = 13350`. It should be `where symbol='15369-2017-02'`

Comment: @Nick I also used same but it also don't work..I have edited my question too with same approach.

Comment: You use `TRIM` in your `SELECT` query perhaps you also need it in your `UPDATE` query? Also your MySQL command panel uses `re_value`, not `symbol`, which is correct?

Comment: sorry @Nick I edited  my question. still it doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't have a parameter to the `execute` call for the `UPDATE`, it should be `$q->execute();`, not `$q->execute($sql);`. That is what is probably causing it to fail.

Comment: When I remove $sql and use instead execute(); only it throws me error of PDO Statement but whne i place $sql inside it run without error and also display value but old not updated

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: But what *exactly* is the error?

Comment: Thanks @Nick Solved it with your suggestion.

Comment: Good to hear. If you think the solution has value to other users, you should post it as an answer and accept it, otherwise just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this query [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO entrance(name,symbol) VALUES ($a,$b) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'Sagar Rawal';
```

**Why your current approach doesn't work?** See *Nick's* comment below your question

Comment: but symbol is not the Primary key. Id is Primary key. But I want when symbol is same since I'm using as roll no which must be Primary key. then how can I use your approach?

Comment: @redface what about this line `$STH->execute(array(symbol));` look carefully you're not binding symbol properly

Comment: I have edited my question so that others will find easy to understand. In that line I have $STH->execute(array($d)); where &d=symbol. It run sucessfully and also insert new row when symbol value is different. Only when symbol  is same it won't update.